# Carregar projetos de Visual Studio para VsCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, asp-net-core

Boa noite a todos!
Sempre desenvolvi minhas aplicações web em C# com Visual Studio, porém agora por necessidade estou precisando ir para o Visual Code.
Será que poderiam me dar umas dicas de como utilizar o Visual Code em aplicações já iniciadas em Visual Studio? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendo a leitura da documentação do visual studio code. Ele é bem simples de utilizar, porém, será necessário a instalação de alguns plugins e deverá avaliar a necessidade de qual a configuração do depurador .NET Core, conforme a necessidade do seu projeto.
[Working with C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp)